# What is the best way to defeat The Fury non-lethally in MGS3?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, metal-gear-solid-hd-collection

I am having a hard time trying do defeat The Fury **non-lethally** in Hard difficulty in MGS3. I followed some YouTube videos, however after the first shot with the Mosin Garant, he won't stop running after me, since he has great audition and sight.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the best way is hiding in the red door at the opposite side from where you entered. If he burns there, run away and return when the flames have extinguished.

Comment: Did your answer work for you? If it didn't, then it might pay to set up some bombs (I prefer manually detonated explosives) and blow them up away from the fury (while you and your explosives are out of sight) to distract him and land an easy shot at his rear.

Answer (score 4):

Another easy way is to use stun grenades. Wait until he does his countdown, when he hits zero throw a stun grenade at the end of the hall he's rocketing down.